# How to get Ant Design Form data in another Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, antd

I've created a form using Ant design's Form.create() and i want to access it's field's values in another component. Using redux, i can do that using:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    formStates: getFormValues('form')(state), 
  };
}
```

is there a way to do that for Ant design's Forms?

Answer (score 1):

It can get the field values if the other component is inside `Form.create()`.

Once the field has been registered with `getFieldDecorator`, you can access the value by `props.form.getFieldValue('fieldName')`.